# clearing dates from bootstrap datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker. I need to show selected dates from the datepicker to the div at right hand side along with a trash symbol. when i click on trash symbol , the selected date need to be cleared from bootstrap datepicker also. But i do not know how to do it? Do you have any ideas?

I tried:

```
$('.datepickerBootstrap').datepicker("clearDates");
```

But it clears all dates.

Also tried with

```
$('.datepickerBootstrap').datepicker('update', '');
```

check out my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/f2p8v3co/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should  work if you want to clear out the date. Update your fiddle with this code

```
$('.datepickerBootstrap').datepicker('update', '');
```

But if you want to update the date then you should use

```
$('.datepickerBootstrap').datepicker('setDates', '');
```

Hope it helps